# Studio flow SMS reply to "Send and wait for reply" with 10DLC registered number not working

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-studio

If I trigger a Studio flow via the REST API trigger, SMS replies to a sent message work fine as long as the Twilio number used is *not * connected to a messaging service.

I expect the "Send and wait for reply" widget in this flow to be triggered by an SMS response no matter what. It seems like the new 10DLC restrictions are interfering with this process and replies are ignored if the number *is* registered to a messaging service.

I don't want to get fined for sending messages in the associated flow by removing the sending number from a messaging service, but that's the only way to handle it right now. It seems like Twilio needs to add an option to associate a number with a REST API url instead of just a Webhook url.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, each Flow Execution will have a binding between a To and From sender, and your outbound message is between the two phone numbers as set in your API request, but your inbound is between the Messaging Service (because that phone number is a part of it) and the end users number - which is a separate binding, so another execution is created.

If you are using a number from a messaging service and triggering a flow using Rest API, you will have to follow the below steps:

1. The Rest API request should include the Messaging service SID in the place of From number.
2. The integration page in messaging service is set to defer incoming messages to sender’s webhook.
3. In the phone numbers section handle the incoming messages with the studio flow.

For reference:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/studio-faq#why-does-every-incoming-message-create-a-new-execution